# Count ways to form isosceles triangles

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Their are N persons sitting on a table with N vertices.We need to count the number of isosceles triangles formed such that each vertex of the triangle is a vertex of the table and all persons seating on these 3 vertices are of same gender.

**Example :** Let 0=Male and 1=Female and seating arrangment in clockwise direction is as follow : 1101010

Then answer is 3.

**Explanation** : Indices of vertices of the three monochromatic isosceles triangles are (0,3,5), (1,3,5) and (2,4,6) (assuming indices
start from 0)

Now how to find this count for given arrangement string.

Comment: Is this table circular, and are the people sitting evenly spaced?

Comment: This was [a problem](http://www.codechef.com/INSM2014/problems/INSM01) from a contest (Insomnia 2014) which was live at the time of OP posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pseudo-code algorithm will count them:

```
x = '1101010'
Cnt = 0
N = length(x)
i = 0             /* First Vertex */
while i < N begin
    c = 1    /* Length of the two equal sides */
    while c < N/2.0 begin
        j = (i + c) mod N         /* Second vertex */
        k = (j + c) mod N         /* Third vertex */
        if x[i] = x[j] and x[i] = x[k] begin    /* Check for same gender */
            Cnt = Cnt + 1    /* Found an isosceles - count and print it */
            print i + ',' + j + ',' + k
        end
        c = c + 1
    end
    i = i + 1
end
print Cnt    /* Print the answer */
```